# Where can you download Steven Smith's ASP.NET Cache Manager?

Tags: asp.net, caching

I found this interesting ASP.NET Cache Management tool recently. Looks great, but the only website I can find where you can download it doesn't seem to be functioning:

http://aspalliance.com/cachemanager/

Does anyone know where else I can find this?

Comment: Check out the link below but if possible, you should try to inform the author about the broken site @ http://stevesmithblog.com/contact/

Comment: aspalliance.com was purchased by codeproject.com a few years ago (as part of a larger transaction). I no longer have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

I've added a sample project that includes the required DLL to Github. The source for the CacheManager DLL is not currently available, but this will at least let you add CacheManager to your own projects easily enough.

https://github.com/ardalis/CacheManagerSample

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ASPAlliance is having login issues, when I put in my email to reset password I get this:

> If you've forgotten your password, you
>   can reset it using this page. An email
>   will be sent to your account's address
>   containing a URL you can use to update
>   your profile with a new password. This
>   process also confirms that your
>   account email address is valid. Simply
>   enter your email into the box below
>   and click the 'Confirm Account'
>   button, then check your email in a few
>   moments and you should find the
>   message. The special URL within the
>   email is only valid for a few hours,
>   so please complete the confirmation
>   process by clicking the URL in the
>   message at your earliest convenience.
>
> Unable to connect to validation
>   server.